# RLM False Virtual Machine Detection

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, license

I have recently installed software with [RLM (Reprise Licence Manager)](https://www.reprisesoftware.com/) licensing protection after completing the setup and running RLM, **I get an error indicating that server has detected that I'm running the server on a virtual machine, which I'm not** with this error:

```
 (rlm)  You are attempting to run the server on a virtual machine
```

and the server refuses to start and validating my license (I am running a normal windows 10 home edition.)

Software vendor who has used the RLM system has declared this:
[In Case of False Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud36q.png)

And I have deleted all of my bridged connections once but it doesn't resolve the problem.

So my question is how virtual machine detection works and how can I prevent this.

Comment: After removing bridged connections did you reboot before trying again? Windows has an irritating habit of leaving remnants around until the next reboot. Considering you have bridged connections... Do you have VMWare, VirtualBox, Hyper-V or another virtualization product installed ? I have seen some cases of the mere presence of a virtualization product on the computer triggering a false positive because the check did not correctly distinguish between virtual host and guest.

Comment: Another [false positive](http://www.reprisesoftware.com/admin/software-licensing-issues.php) : "If a flash drive is plugged into a machine, it is incorrectly identified as a virtual machine. This is fixed in rlm v14.0BL1". Your version might not include this fix.

Comment: @Tonny Yes, I have bridged [SoftEther](https://www.softether.org/) connection and  I have rebooted the system after deleting the connections. 
I have had installed a VMware sometime ago but after seeing the error, I have uninstalled it which did not help.

Comment: @harrymc I'm using rlm software **version v9.4 (build:4)
rlm comm version: v1.2** which I have got from the software developer,The server package name is **FLT7.1v1**. is it the manufacturer's responsibility to update the rlm?

Comment: Do you have connected flash drives? For assigning responsibility, this depends on your contract with the manufacturer (if any exists).

Comment: @harrymc No, I don't have any flash drives connected to the system. mouse, keyboard, wifi adapter, and pen tablet are the only devices that are connected to the system.
the manufacturer is willing to help on the problem and they asked for a diagnostic file but they couldn't find the problem in it.

Answer (score 1):

The advice I can give is to
ask the manufacturer of the software to use the latest version of RLM,
in the hope that this would eliminate this false positive.

If they do so and the problem disappears, then all is fine; but if the problem
stays then it is the problem of Reprise and not of the manufacturer.

However, so long as the manufacturer is using a deprecated version of RLM,
the problem in my opinion is theirs.